# How to use onkeydown-onkeypress-onkeyup on this exercise

Tags: javascript, html

create two text boxes.User will give from keyboard in the first text box and in  the second text box will take the variable from the first text box and will make the characters caps locks.Example :i give e inside the first text box on the second box will be E.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>exc1</title>
        <script>
        function create() {
        var x = document.getElementById("textbox").value;


        }
        function takevariable(x){

        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="textbox" onkeydown="create()">
    <input type="text" id="textbox" onkeypress="takevariable()">

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are giving same id to the both text element, ids should be unique so I am renaming them with textboxfrom and textboxto. Second, here you should also need to listen keyup event aswell, otherwise you wont't get last character in the second box. Because for single character entry, browser enters character just when it fires keyup event.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>exc1</title>
        <script>
        function create() {
            var x = document.getElementById("textboxfrom").value;
        }
        function takevariable(x){
            document.getElementById("textboxto").value = document.getElementById("textboxfrom").value.toUpperCase();
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="textboxfrom" onkeydown="create()" onkeypress="takevariable()" onkeyup="takevariable()">
        <input type="text" id="textboxto" >
    </body>
</html>
```